# Salesforce Code Coverage Failure: Cannot deploy Apex Trigger in Production code coverage in Sandbox is 57%

Tags: salesforce, code-coverage

I am trying to deploy a trigger in production and despite having 57% code coverage in Sandbox, I get the following error

Code Coverage Failure
Your code coverage is 0%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.
Business_Hours

What am I missing:

My trigger is:

```
trigger Business_Hours on Lead (before insert) {
//Selecting default business hours (BH) record
BusinessHours defaultBH = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true Limit 1];
//Making sure BH record exists
if(defaultBH != NULL){
    for(Lead leadObj : trigger.new ){
        //Making sure that first call made field is populated and is updated
        if(leadObj.Call_Made__c != NULL && Trigger.oldMap.get(leadObj.Id).Call_Made__c != leadObj.Call_Made__c){
            //For BH method assign (BH record id, CreatedDate, Call_Made)
            decimal result = BusinessHours.diff(defaultBH.Id, leadObj.CreatedDate, leadObj.Call_Made__c );
           
            Decimal resultingMinutes = result/(60000);
            //Populating result into our custom field & setting number of decimals
            leadObj.Elapsed_Time__c = resultingMinutes.setScale(4); 
        }  
    }    
}
```

}

Test Class:

```
 @isTest

public class Business_Hours_Test
{
    static testMethod void testUnit()
    {
        
        
        Lead led = new Lead();
        led.lastname = 'Test';
        led.firstName ='Test';
        led.company = 'ABC';
        led.Brand__c = 'Rain';
        led.Call_Made__c = System.today();
        led.CreatedDate = System.today();
        led.Elapsed_Time__c = 736;
        // Add all required field
        update led;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `update led;`? Shouldn't it be `insert`? Are you positive you're deploying the test too, not just the trigger?

Answer (score 1):

I went through the code and have a few observations:

1. The trigger is running in before insert where you will never be able to get **Trigger.oldMap**, as it's null for insert triggers.
2. The test class should throw an error as you are updating a record without inserting it.
3. To accomplish this you will have to create a lead and then update to modify the **Call_Made__c** parameter. Furthermore, the trigger should run in before update.